# Если несколько минимальных, как их вывести? Си

Tags: c

В задании нужно вынести номер столбца с минимальной суммой элементов. Если этих столбца 2, как вывести 2 номера? Пример:

```
1 1 1
1 1 0
1 1 3
0 1
```

Где 0 и 1 - необходимый ответ

```
#define N 100
void inpElMat(int s[][N], int a,int b) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < b; j++) {
            scanf_s("%d", &s[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return;
}

int colSum(int s[][N], int str, int col) {
    int sum = 0,min = 0, imin = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++) {
        for (int j = sum = 0; j < col; j++) {
            sum += s[j][i];
        }
        if (i == 0 || sum < min) {
            min = sum;
            imin = i;
        }
    }
    return imin;
}
int main() {
    int mat[N][N];
    int n,k,a = 0,min = 0;
    setlocale(0, "");
    printf("Введите размер матрицы");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    inpElMat(mat, n,k);
    min = colSum(mat, n, k);
    printf("%d ", min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Заготовить массив для минимальных индексов?...

Comment: А можете подсказать, как заготовить такой массив?

Comment: Ну вы же двумерный массив mat делали, одномерный чуть проще ;)

Comment: `int min_idx[N];`

Comment: Понимаете, тут вопрос скорее состоит не как "Ой, а как же объявить массив", а в том, как "ЗАСУНУТЬ ИНДЕКСЫ СТОЛБЦОВ В МАССИВ И РЕТУРНУТЬ ЕГО". Так что не вижу смысла в подколах, которые оставляет тут MBo. Не можешь помочь - не пиши.

Comment: Передайте в функцию массив для индексов столбцов с одинаковой минимальной суммой, а верните количество элементов, записанных в этот массив